# how i put my menu item in same line with logo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

End trainer I want to build my first blog, I faced a problem I can't control in my header of page can anyone help?

This is my page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar"> <!--<![endif]-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myblogspot.css">
    <title> مدونة الراقي التقني </title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="top_header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="D:\only me\work\myblog\logo.png" height="150" width="150"></div>
            <div id="main_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>الربح من الانترنت</li>
                    <li>تكنلوجيا</li>
                    <li>تسويق إلكتروني</li>
                    <li>تصميم</li>
                    <li>خدمات</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <header>
   <div id="top_header">

     <div id="main_menu">
       <ul >
         <li class="logo"><img src="D:\only me\work\myblog\logo.png" height="150" width="150"></li>
         <li>الربح من الانترنت</li>
         <li>تكنلوجيا</li>
         <li>تسويق إلكتروني</li>
         <li>تصميم</li>
         <li>خدمات</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </header>
```

css

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;

}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
 
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of your css file.
Here is my working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>مدونة الراقي التقني</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="top_header">
        <div id="logo" style="display: inline">
          <img src="D:\only me\work\myblog\logo.png" height="150" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div id="main_menu" style="display: inline">
          <ul style="display: inline-block">
            <li>123</li>
            <li>123</li>
            <li>123</li>
            <li>123</li>
            <li>123</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you meant, but I understood your request the way I reflected it in my decision. Also, you did not show your css.

In order to place the menu items on the same line with the logo, just add the flex rule to the `#top_neader` selector:

```
#top_header {
  display: flex;
}
```

Also, you have an inconsistent html structure at the beginning. You are specifying the `<html>` tag twice:

```
...
<html>
<head>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar"> <!--<![endif]-->
...
```

You can also change the order and location of flex objects using many flex rules.

Was it necessary?

```css
#top_header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myblogspot.css">
    <title> مدونة الراقي التقني </title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="top_header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="D:\only me\work\myblog\logo.png" height="150" width="150"></div>
            <div id="main_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>الربح من الانترنت</li>
                    <li>تكنلوجيا</li>
                    <li>تسويق إلكتروني</li>
                    <li>تصميم</li>
                    <li>خدمات</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #top_header{

  clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    display:inline-block;
text-transform:lowercase;
width:auto;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:47.5px;
padding-right:47.5px;
padding-top:9px;
padding-bottom:9px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#57fafc;
text-align:center;
background-color:#62d2d3;
}

#logo{
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}

#main_menu{
 float: left;
}

 li
{
display:inline-block;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul
{
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
padding: 0px;
margin:0px;
}

Comment: I ran the code with your css, and I saw that the menu items to the left of the logo are in one line. What result do you want to see? Take a screenshot of the desired result and I will do it the way you want. And a tip: don't use the `float` rule. This rule is used in rare and urgent cases.